# How to Bind the data from a Hashset to ItemTemplate in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hashtable, itemtemplate

I created item template inside a GridView.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Enabled='<%# Eval("id") %>' 
                    Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Now my issue is I am storing the "id" in a hash set because I have some duplicate ID's and I want to display only unique ID's

```
var id = new HashSet<String>();
id.Add("1");
id.Add("1");
id.Add("2");
id.Add("3");
id.Add("4");
id.Add("5");
Gridview1.DataSource=id;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

I think something is worong with the Eval method and I don't think it is getting the value from Hashset.

Can somebody explain me how to bind the data from Hashste to Eval?

Also, it was working if I dint use ItemTemplate, I mean I can just fill the gridiew directly from Hashset value. However, I am trying to make nested gridview hence using Item Template.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You're using `Eval` on a `Collection`.

Comment: Yes, Because I thought it will work on collection. What else can I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you name a variable `id` the underlying type does not contain a property `id`.

You could use an anonymous type as `DataSource`:

```
var ids = new HashSet<String>();
ids.Add("1");
ids.Add("1");
ids.Add("2");
ids.Add("3");
ids.Add("4");
ids.Add("5");
Gridview1.DataSource = ids.Select(id => new { id }).ToList();
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

However, you are trying to set a boolean property (`Enabled`) from an `Id`. That seems to be incorrect.

(note that i've changed the name of the `HashSet` from `id` to `ids` since it contains multiples)

Comment: Hi, I am getting "Specified cast is not valid". Can you cast the HashSet that way?

Comment: @John: Have you noticed that you are trying to set the `bool` property `Enabled` with your id?!

Comment: Yes. How else would I set it?

Comment: @John: I assume you want to set the `Text` property instead.

Comment: Got you. That was lame. I think it will work now. Thanks a Ton Tim. Have a great day.